# How to re-add file to stage area (in precommit hook)?

Tags: git

I would like replace revision number in my `index.html` file prior commit. Here is my `pre-commit` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

revision_number=`git shortlog | wc -l`;

exec ./.git/hooks/replace_revision.py $((revision_number - 2))

git reset HEAD app/index.html
git add app/index.html
```

Revision changes, but git commits file without change - with old number revision, hence just after `git commit -a`, `git diff` shows me change in revision line in `index.html` file.

Instead of `reset...` I tried also: `git update-index --again`.

How I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work (since git 5.4), as:

`@commit.c line 811`

```
/*
 * Re-read the index as pre-commit hook could have updated it,
 * and write it out as a tree.  We must do this before we invoke
 * the editor and after we invoke run_status above.
 */
discard_cache();
read_cache_from(index_file);
```

I also tried this and it works for me. Are you sure you have the `pre-commit` hook and not the `pre-commit-msg` hook?
Is this the only hook you have set up?

*Note:* You don’t need the `git reset`, you are undoing that with `git add` anyways.